# Vue component using computed property of the mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple component that uses mixin that's shared across multiple components with similar functionality.

When I run it I seem to be getting

> Property or method "activeClass" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render.

Here's my mixin

```js
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                opened: false,
                identity: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            activeClass() {
                return {
                    active: this.opened
                };
            }
        },
        created() {
            window.EventHandler.listen(this.identity + '-toggled', opened => this.opened = opened);
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                window.EventHandler.fire('toggle-' + this.identity);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and my component

```js
<template>
    <span class="pointer" :class="activeClass" @click="toggle"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
</template>
<script>
    import Trigger from '../../mixins/Trigger';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                mixins: [Trigger],
                data() {
                    return {
                        identity: 'language'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

For some reason I cannot seem to be able to access `activeClass` computed property from within the component. Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to move mixin to components main scope. Not in data function rerurn

Comment: Of course - you know I’ve been staring at it for quite sometime and didn’t realise. Thanks very much.